# Bike Friday Pocket Llama and Magura MT Trail Series 2

Tags: disc-brake, magura, bike-friday

I'm new to disc brakes and today I tried to fit a Magura MT Trail Series 2-piston brake to my Bike Friday Pocket Llama frame. However, although I'd be able to attach the caliper to the frame, it does not seem to fit perfectly.

Do I need an adapter or a different caliper, or can I just mount the brake on the frame even though it is not a perfect fit?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Do I need the Magura QM 12 adaptor to change from the IS mounting standard to the Postmount standard?

https://magura.com/en/EUR/bicyle/original_spare_parts/adapters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that spacers on both sides will do the job. I hope this is a good and stable approach and a correct way to mount the caliper.

[image]

Comment: Does your rotor align correctly with the pads?

Comment: I'll have to check and report back.

Comment: How did it go, were spacers a feasible fix?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you. Yes, it works well :)

Comment: No worries, it just adds some value to such questions when there is closure, so you may also check this as self-answer. Did you just go by eye/feel or is there any information about the spacers and size? Just wondering how this ties in with mounting "standards" - I think most post-mount calipers usually screw in from one side?

Comment: I just went by eye/feel :)